# Where to put access token in Reddit API url?

Tags: json, api, oauth, reddit

I'm trying to use the reddit api in a practice app to practice parsing JSON in Swift, and I've registered to get an access token, but now I'm confused as to where to put it. In other APIs I've used, I'd just put the access token string (?) somewhere in the endpoint url and that would be it, but I can't see anything pertaining to that in the documentation. For example if I'm trying to access `https://api.reddit.com/api/v1/top/`, where would I add my access token?

In the OAuth documentation is says to use the url `https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/authorize?client_id=CLIENT_ID&response_type=TYPE&
    state=RANDOM_STRING&redirect_uri=URI&duration=DURATION&scope=SCOPE_STRING` but that seems to need:

`CLIENT_ID`

`RANDOM_STRING`

`URI`

`DURATION`

`SCOPE_STRING`

I plugged in all the necessary values according to the documentation, and it redirected me to the front page of reddit (I gave https://www.reddit.com/ as my redirect uri)

In previous practice apps with other APIs, I would simply have a single url (that included my auth token) and I'd plug that url into my function that parses the data. Now that I've followed the OAuth directions, I still can't seem to find an endpoint url that I can use in my app.

I tried `https://api.reddit.com/api/v1/top` in my browser and it says `{"message": "Unauthorized", "error": 401}`, and I tried `https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/myAccessToken` where `myAccessToken` is the string they gave me when I registered. This leads me to a "page not found" on Reddit.

What do I need to do here to get a basic endpoint url that gives me the JSON data for, just for example, recent posts?

Comment: You may find this useful - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28955541/how-to-get-access-token-reddit-api.

Comment: @MoA thanks, that doesn't seem to be in Swift though