# Reddit Api Get Access Token

Tags: python, api, token, reddit, bearer-token

Hi I want to get access token for my reddit account? I'm trying to login with my https://ssl.reddit.com/api/v1/access_token email address and password but it doesn't work. Thanks!
ı try that

```py
import requests
r = requests.get("https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/access_token?grant_type=password&username=Emrovsky&password=mypass!")
```

Comment: Did you try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29038271/8315934)?

Comment: yes i tried to get to this address like

Comment: ```py
r = requests.get("https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/access_token?grant_type=password&username=Emrovsky&password=mypass!")```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed the steps in [the post I linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28955541/how-to-get-access-token-reddit-api/29038271#29038271) and it worked. Here's the Python code:

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

data = {
    'grant_type': 'password',
    'username': '{your username}',
    'password': '{your password}'
}

r = requests.post("https://ssl.reddit.com/api/v1/access_token",
                  data=data,
                  auth=HTTPBasicAuth('{your apps client id}', '{your apps secret key}'))

print(r.text)
```

> USERNAME must be registered as a developer of the OAuth 2 client ID you send.

and obviously the app needs to have been created.

Comment: but ı want to get my accounts bearer token :(

Comment: how are you going to use it?

Comment: ı want to get my accounts statistics

Comment: Okay then go to your reddit settings, create an app for personal use, and follow the steps I described.